# How to get a list of lat/long values between two locations to show a polyline by street in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, polygon, polyline

[image: MAP]

```
polyLine.add(Polyline(
  polylineId: PolylineId("route1"),
  color: Colors.blue,
  patterns: [
    PatternItem.dash(20.0),
    PatternItem.gap(10)
  ],
  width: 3,
  points: [
    LatLng(
      40.90555,
      -74.0078533,
    ),
    LatLng(
      40.844617,
      -73.902427,
    )
  ],
));
```

I am using this package: [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

I need a list of lat/long points that display a road between these two points since when I try to show a polyline in Google Maps, it just shows a straight line.

In short, I want to display the road between these two points on a Google Map.

If you have another method for doing this, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Maybe you can fetch from the API, otherwise add a screen to select the address (Start & End) like Google map. Explore a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this package

[flutter_polyline_points](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points)

This will give you all the coordinates between two lat lng which will help you to draw a polyline

you can find the tutorial here

https://blog.codemagic.io/creating-a-route-calculator-using-google-maps/